# Limits set in the php.ini file

Tags: php

I have a system where I want users to be able to download large amounts of data. Some of the files can be over 800 MB. The problem is that php times out before the download is complete. I can get just under 250 MB worth, someone on a slower computer got considerably less.

I've think the problem lies in the php.ini file have increased some of the values which hasn't made any difference. I've found three sections of the file that possibly need to be changed but I don't know what they do and can't seem to find out in the php manual. I was wondering if somebody could tell me what they could do and it this could affect my issue.

```
; Default timeout for socket based streams (seconds)
default_socket_timeout = 360


; Connect timeout
;mssql.connect_timeout = 5

; Query timeout
;mssql.timeout = 60


; Default timeout in seconds.
pfpro.defaulttimeout = 30
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How are you allowing them to download the data? How are you sending the file to their browser? It should be fast and almost memory free if you're using `readfile()`

Comment: It's putting all the files they want to download into a zip file and downloading that.

Comment: Do you really let someone download stuff via a web browser that is 800MB in size? And timeout , means that you are fetching the contnet via php? Not letting download the file directly?

Comment: What else would you suggest?

Comment: Can anyone help me with understanding the code I posted? That was the main part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: Does that go in the ini file?

Comment: No, you can use it at the top of your script

Comment: That isn't in there at the presnet so I'll try including it and see if it helps. I'll let you know.

Comment: I tried that out but it didn't seem to have any affect.

Answer (score 0):

This is a likely candidate to have its value raised:

```
max_execution_time -  1800
```